# Maven Build Project never finishes on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, pom.xml

When I open a Spring Boot application, and it tries to Build the dependencies that I am using in the files, the process never completes. I have left it running for hours with absolutely no progress on the following message in the terminal:

```
9f5bcec9 Importing Maven project(s): Importing Maven project(s) - Refreshing '/jdt.ls-java-project'. [337/1000]
c9f76cf2 Refreshing Maven model:  [0/-1]
fc8986d3 Repository registry initialization [Done]
```

I have a feeling that this is a result of a mistake that I missed in my pom.xml file, considering it has something to do with my dependencies. I ask that someone looks through my pom.xml and finds the issues that might be causing them, and the ways to solve them. This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.thinhda.spring.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>Spring grpc and http</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
                <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
                <!-- <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration> -->
            <!-- </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Does the project build correctly when you run maven outside of VSCode?

Comment: No, not on IntelliJ at least.

Comment: Does it Build correctly from the command line?  What phase does it reach?

Comment: I did the following command: mvn clean install (but this also applies to other commands that undergo the build phase). This is where it gets stuck: ```--------------------< com.thinhda.spring.grpc:core >--------------------
[INFO] Building core 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
```

Comment: It never finishes building.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your dependency on `io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:4.4.5` is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.1.  According to the [`grpc-spring-boot-starter` release notes](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md), the starter's version 4.8.0 supports Spring Boot 2.7.1 and gRPC 1.47.0.  You already have gRPC 1.47.0 in your POM so I think with this change you'll be good.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```